# How Can You Run CRaSH Commands Or A Script On Node Startup?

Tags: corda

I need to initialise my Corda nodes by running a few flows to create certain states.

At the moment I am doing it via the CRaSH shell. 
e.g.

```
flow start IOUFlow iouValue: 50, counterparty: Bank1
```

Is it possible to have the node run a script or some commands on node startup to do this automatically?

If not, how can I write a bash script to automate these CRaSH commands?

Comment: You can just write a bash script to SSH into the node shell and execute the flow after the node has started. You can do this at the end of your bootstrapping script/user data.

Comment: What if the bootstrapping is done via `gradlew deployNodes` and the nodes are running locally in a terminal?

Comment: use a `doLast` in gradle and implement ssh with retries and timeout. or simply use wait/sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Corda 4.4 introduces a new feature to register actions to be performed on node startup.

You could register an action to be performed on node startup using a CordaService.

```
appServiceHub.register(
    AppServiceHub.SERVICE_PRIORITY_NORMAL,
    event -> {
        // Your custom code to be run on startup.
    }
);
```

You might want to check on the event type to keep it future proof, but currently the `ServiceLifecycleEvent` just has a single `STATE_MACHINE_STARTED` enum.